# Unix - Split a file containing XML files into single files

Tags: xml, file, unix, grep

I've been working on a piece of code that splits a file containing multiple XML files into individual XML files. The line count of each XML file varies so I have been using the XML head tag to know where the next file starts.

```
grep -n $string $xmlfile | sed -n 's/^\([0-9]*\)[:].*/\1p'
```

Which gets me the line number of the start of each file. How can I use the head/tail command to make use of the line numbers to pull the files apart within a single automated script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// x1, x2 being XML declaration line numbers
cat myfile | head -n x2 | tail -n x1
```

Comment: Not too sure how to get the variable amount of line declarations into the x1/x2 etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Loop over the list of line numbers `m1,m2,...,mn`. Let `x1=0` and `x2=n1`. For each subsequent iteration assign `x1=mi-1` and `x2=mi` (1,2,i,n should be interpreted as indices mathematically).

Answer (score 0):

When parsing `xml` files in your prefered `shell`, your best bet will be to use `xmllint` command-line and `Xpath` expressions.

---

`xmllint` comes from `libxml`.

See http://www.xmlsoft.org/ & http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpath

Comment: Unfortunately neither are installed on the machine and I don't have the rights to install. Will need to look into libxml and Xpath when I get to another machine.